# Describe the curve $r=⟨t,t^2,\cos(t)⟩$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Describe the curve $r=⟨t,t^2,\cos(t)⟩$

I'm confused as to how I 'describe' the curve here?

Comment: what about plot it? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28t%2Ct%5E2%2Ccos+t%29%2C+-5%3Ct%3C5

Comment: What does it look like if you look down at it from high above ($z$ very large)? What can you say about it's $z$ coordinate; can it be very large? It's a graph you probably know. How can you unite the two observations (the $x-y$ with the $z$ together)?

Comment: It looks like a rippling parabola. Can you see it?

Comment: @JohnDouma yes, I've been practicing.  I think I'm getting the hang of it now